# Is it possible to keep custom URL prefix over all urls generated later in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to keep some custom Url context over all MVC generated urls. There is my situation: Users in several roles are accessing my website over URL with prefix by their roles (i.e. .../admin/{controller}/...). It is a requirement for my project, it has to be this way. I want to keep the user role context in every url generated later in views, controlers, etc. (methods like Html.ActionLink, Url.Action, RedirectTo, ...)

My routes definitions in RouteConfig.cs:

```
// guest route
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Guest",
    url: "guest/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, userContext = UserRoles.Guest }
);

// authentized user
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "User",
    url: "user/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, userContext = UserRoles.User }
);

// authentized admin 
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Admin",
    url: "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, userContext = UserRoles.Admin }
);
```

Then in BaseController (every other controller inherit from that):

```
protected UserRoles CurrentRole = UserRoles.Admin;
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    CurrentRole = (UserRoles)RouteData.Values["userContext"];

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

So I have `CurrentRole` property in every controller/action and view (given CurrentRole to ViewBag). I can make context urls by adding the routeValues `new {userContext = CurrentRole}` to the url using methods.

BUT!!! I have allready crated this website without the user context and don't want to rewrite every using of method like this or create own custom (Html, Url) extensions to cover every usage of url using method. I want to create some override of `Url.GenerateUrl()` or something else whitch would keep my user context.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your route to this so that Html.ActionLink, Url.Action, RedirectTo will use the current user context.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "WithUserContext",
    url: "{usercontext}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { usercontext = "guest|user|admin" }
);
```

Comment: Thank you, it helps. But I must do switch on RouteData.Values["userContext"] in Base controller in OnActionExecuting method to assign some of UserRoles enum to protected CurrentRole. Is there any way to assign something from UserRoles enum to userContext in this route insteed of strings?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by assign something from UserRoles enum to userContext? I don't understand it unfortunately

Comment: Ok. I have defined enum UserRoles witch contains the roles which user can achieve. I used it in my routes from my question. After that routes was the RouteData.Values["userContext"] set to one role from the UserRoles enum... But this is not needed anymore, I like the way you solved this. Thank you once more